# Как правильно записать данные и вывести их в таблицу?

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms

Хочу вывести данные в таблицу через `asp:Repeater`

Вот такого типа -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос как это сделать? Вот такой я код набросал создал класс `ComputerInfo.cs`

```
    public string IP { set; get; }
    public List<string> ComputerName { set; get; }

    public List<string> GetHostname()
    {
        for (int i = 10; i <= 13; i++)
        {
            IP = "192.168.4." + i;
            try
            {
                ComputerName.Add(Dns.GetHostEntry(IP).HostName);
            }
            catch
            {
                ComputerName.Add("Нет компа");
                continue;
            }
        }
        return ComputerName;
    }
```

Правильно ли я сделал? Ниже вызов этого метода.

```
    ComputerInfo comp = new ComputerInfo();
    ReapeterContacts.DataSource = comp.GetHostname().ToList();
    ReapeterContacts.DataBind();
```

Получается мне нужно сделать `List` типа ("192.168.4.10","rdc")  и затем выводить в таблицу? Или может я не прав?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Занесите в таблицу полученные данные

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Computers");
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IP", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));

for (int i = 10; i <= 13; i++)
{
    string ip = "192.168.4." + i;
    string name;

    try
    {
        name = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).HostName;
    }
    catch
    {
        name = "Нет компа";
    }

    dt.Rows.Add(ip, name);
}

ReapeterContacts.DataSource = dt;
RepeaterContacts.DataBind();
```

Затем выводите в рипитер

```
<div class="Item">
    <span>
        <asp:Label ID="IP" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IP").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
    </span>
    <span>
        <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
    </span>
</div>
```

В целом как то так должно выглядеть.